# What is the format for a cookie with multiple key value pairs using CURLOPT_COOKIE

Tags: php, curl, cookies, web, web-scraping

I'm scraping a site where, if I use my browser and click through the T.O.S., the page sets a cookie in my browser that looks like this:

**Name**    OnCoreWeb

**Value**   AutoLoadImages=-1&ImageViewer=2&DefaultNumberOfRows=10

The cookie name is OnCoreWeb, but the value is an ampersand delimitted string of three key/value pairs.

When I send the cookie in cURL, I construct it like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "OnCoreWeb={AutoLoadImages=0&ImageViewer=0&DefaultNumberOfRows=50});
```

But when I output the headers, the Set-Cookie seems to append an extra value pair to the end of the first cookie, like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: OnCoreWeb={AutoLoadImages=0&ImageViewer=0&DefaultNumberOfRows=50}&AutoLoadImages=-1; expires=Mon, 21-Aug-2017 00:36:44 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Date: Sun, 21 Aug 2016 00:36:44 GMT

You can see that in the Set-Cookie line, a `&AutoLoadImages=-1;` is appended right after the closing `}`. This makes me think my cookie is somehow formatted wrong.

As a control, I've commented out all the COOKIEJAR and COOKIEFILE lines, so that the only cookie setting is done via the CURLOPT_COOKIE property.

As I think about this, I guess you could say the cookie VALUE is just a string, and the parsing is done server side, so wrapping the string in {} doesn't really magically make the string into an array. With this philosophy, I also tried wrapping the string in '' (double single-quotes), which also didn't make any difference. I guess I should try removing the {} or '' altogether, since the cookie value is merely a string, and the ampersands don't mean a thing client-side. Something server-side decides to parse the string using a "&" as the delimiter.

And magically, just like that, by removing the {} or '' wrapper around the cookie value string, the extra, superfluous `&AutoLoadImages=-1;` disappeared.

The new header appears correct, and looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=yqtxvba24xodegufrkoih355; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: OnCoreWeb=AutoLoadImages=0&ImageViewer=0&DefaultNumberOfRows=50; expires=Mon, 21-Aug-2017 17:35:12 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 21 Aug 2016 17:35:12 GMT
```

Answer (score 1):

If sniffing http header you found `AutoLoadImages` twice in `Set-Cookie` Http response it is only because a Server behaviour.

IMHO this data cookie encoding it seems a little strange and I could agree it look like wrong, but given that it is a server side behaviour we cannot assume anything about it.

I'll suggest to try browsing the site and see which kind/format of data you'll receive.

Comment: Why this downvote? Please comment. I'm really curious to understand and improve my answer if it is possible or, on the other hand, even remove it if it is absolutely wrong.

Comment: I did not downvote you. Even my profile says "Downvoting is weak and stupid." However, I will point out that your answer did not address my question, which was how to format a cookie. That's what I'm looking for in this question. This doesn't mean your answer has no value, because it does.

Comment: I removed the {} and '' from the cookie value, which is only supposed to be a string. The extra `AutoLoadImages` disappeared.

Comment: A cookie is just a string of text, i have seen it formatted in many ways, people format and store this piece of data as they want. As far as I know, there's no standard about, I have seen json or csv, in plain text or encoded in base64. You're just trying to reverse engineering the behavior of another site. What's I was trying to write is that, in this case, we cannot know what's in developers mind, we can just guess and hope we're right.